# Triggering action of controller of newly created record

Tags: ember.js

I have two sets of controllers/models; lets call them `Food` and `Drink`.

Lets say that my controllers look like this:

```
App.FoodController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    createDrink: function() {
      var drink = this.store.createRecord('drink');
      drink.save()
    }
  }
});

App.DrinkController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    fooBar: function() {
      console.log('Drink created from FoodController');
    }
  }
});
```

What I want to do is to trigger `fooBar` action declared in `DrinkController` after I create new `Drink` record in `FoodController` using `createDrink` at action. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use needs and then grab the controller, and use send.  http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

```
App.FoodController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs:['drink'],
  actions: {
    createDrink: function() {
      var drink = this.store.createRecord('drink');
      drink.save();
      this.get('controllers.drink').send('fooBar');
    }
  }
});
```